# xsl generate attribute with prefix

Tags: xslt, namespaces, prefix

I'm totally new to XSL and have the task of generating output xml with xmlns:A.B.C prefix/value as an attribute of the root node. Specifically like this:

```
<GetVersionResponse xmlns:A.B.C="www.somesite.co.uk/A/B/C">
    <Class>GetVersionRequest</Class>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Text>Some message</Text>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</GetVersionResponse>
```

This is my input:

```
<Error>
    <Namespace>xmlns:A.B.C</Namespace>
    <NamespaceValue>www.somesite.com/A/B/C</NamespaceValue>
    <Class>GetVersionRequest</Class>
    <Message>Some message</Message>
</Error>
```

This is the important snippet from the Error.xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="Error">                    
    <xsl:variable name="ResponseType">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(Class, 'Request'),'Response')"/>
    </xsl:variable>        
    <xsl:variable name="NS">
        <xsl:value-of  select="Namespace"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="NSV">
        <xsl:value-of  select="NamespaceValue"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$ResponseType}" namespace="{$NSV}" xml:space="default">
    ...
</xsl:template
```

It generates the following error because I have a colon in the Namespace element of my input:

XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Unknown namespace prefix

If I replace the colon with an underscore I get the exact out put I require but only with an underscore of course.  Like this:

```
<GetVersionResponse xmlns_A.B.C="www.somesite.co.uk/A/B/C">
    <Class>GetVersionRequest</Class>
    <Errors>
        <Error>
            <Text>Some message</Text>
        </Error>
    </Errors>
</GetVersionResponse>
```

I've trawled the web for hours and think I'm trying to insert the xmlns: as text instead of using the proper objects that will generate xmlns:MYTEXT but cannot figure out how to do it.

Many Thanks for any help !!!!

Comment: But what's the point of adding a namespace declaration that's not used anywhere in the document?

Comment: It's at our client's request, so their system that consumes our web services has an identifier included in the root node for whatever purpose they have for it.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's at *someone*'s request - but that's not what a namespace declaration is for. An "identifier included in the root node" would make sense if it placed the root node - and consequently, the entire document  - inside the given namespace.  But in such case the prefix would be both unnecessary and of no consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complicating factor here is that `xmlns:...` namespace declarations are *not* attributes as far as the XPath data model is concerned, so you can't create them using `xsl:attribute`.  However, in XSLT 2.0 you *can* create them using [`xsl:namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-namespace-nodes).

```
<xsl:template match="Error">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-before(Class, 'Request')}Response">
    <xsl:namespace name="{substring-after(Namespace, 'xmlns:')}"
                   select="NamespaceValue" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="Class" />
    <Errors>
      <Error>
        <Text><xsl:value-of select="Message" /></Text>
      </Error>
    </Errors>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

[Live demo](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ2)

The `name` attribute of `xsl:namespace` is the prefix you want to bind (so *not* including `xmlns:`), and the `select` gives the URI you want to bind it to.

Comment: This is excellent.  Thank you very much for answering so quickly, you've saved me a lot of time here!!!!

Comment: Hi.  I've realised I'm constrained to XSL 1.0 as I'm using .Net and don't want to add  third party refs like Saxon.  I therefore can't use the xsl:namespace.  Currently I've solved by using xsl:choose to detect input class and return specific element:
<xsl:choose>  
 <xsl:when test="Class='GetDrugInformationRequest'">
 <DrugInformationResponse xmlns:HDS.CI.DIR="www.RESIP.co.uk/HDS/CI/DIR" > But it's not very generic and won't react to new input classes.  Any ideas?

Comment: @DP-Dev I don't believe this can be done in XSLT 1.0.  If the `DrugInformationResponse` element were _in_ the required namespace then it would be easy: `<xsl:element name="{substring-after(Namespace, 'xmlns:')}:{substring-before(Class, 'Request')}Response" namespace="{NamespaceValue}">` would create `<HDS.CI.DIR:DrugInformationResponse xmlns:HDS.CI.DIR="...">` - but creating _unused_ namespace bindings dynamically isn't something XSLT 1.0 can do.  It can only create them statically with literal result elements, or by copying namespaces declared on another element in the input tree.